# How do I move all elements of a zipfile set to the prefix directory

Tags: ant, zip

I have a tree that I'd like to zip up and flatten into a single directory.  For example,

```
lib/a/x.jar
lib/y.jar
```

that I'd like to end up in the lib directory of the zip, as follows:

```
lib/x.jar
lib/y.jar
```

I tried the following:

```
<zipfileset  dir="lib" prefix="lib">
    <include name="**/*.jar"  />
</zipfileset>
```

but this results in the same tree in the zip file.  I know that I can define separate file sets, but this seems bad since I would then have to add a file set if I ever added another directory of jars to the lib dir (i.e., it is not very object oriented) and would be prone to leaving the new dir out of the zip.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this 
<include name="*.jar"/> 
instead of 
<include name="**/*.jar"  />
```